# cfscript email validation in coldfusion

Tags: validation, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to get this bit of code in my cfscript tag to work. I've searched and searched but have some up with nothing which will work to validate the email address.

If the email address is blank it will return the errormessage but if I just type on character, it will let it pass.

I'm pretty new to scripting in CF so any help would be appreciated.

```
if (isDefined("form.email"))
            {
                if (form.email is "")
                    {
                        errormessageemail = "Please enter a valid Email Address!";
                    }
                else if (not form.email is "")
                    {
                        email = form.email;
                        function validate_email(str,email) {
                        if( not len(trim(arguments.str)) or not refind("^[0-9A-Za-z.'+_-]+@([0-9A-Za-z-]+\.)+[A-Za-z]+$", trim(arguments.str)) ) {
                            errormessageemail = "Please enter a valid Email Address! Ex. abc@abc.com";
                            }
                        return errormessageemail;
                        }
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be as simple as this:

```
if (StructKeyExists(form, "email") AND NOT isValid("email", form.email)) {
    errormessageemail = "Please enter a valid Email Address!";
}
```

You don't validate if email is not posted. Blank string is not valid email, no need to check it specially.

Note: someone may argue that isValid/email does not work 100% properly. That's true, but rare problem. Use regex if you think so as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help last week. I was always using the isDefined("blah") code in this situation. I've since recoded using the above method and was able to consolidate the logic. you learn something new every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I use for checking for email validity:

```
LOCAL.Email = trim(lCase(ARGUMENTS.Email));
LOCAL.IsValid = reFindNoCase("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)$", LOCAL.Email);
```

And you should test for your form with structKeyExists, not isDefined, like the other respondent suggested.  The structKeyExists function searches a specific scope for the variable. isDefined searches any and every scope.

```
if (StructKeyExists(form, "email") AND NOT isValid("email", form.email)) {
    errormessageemail = "Please enter a valid Email Address!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Simply Email validity Check in CFM**

```
 <cfif  isValid("email", #Form.email#) >
    <cfoutput>Email Address is valid</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
   <cfoutput>Email Address is invalid</cfoutput>
</cfelse>
```

Comment: this functionn will check the email validity either having in correct format or not

Comment: No need to put pound/hash characters around `form.email`